# Solve the recurrence: T(n)=2T(n/2)+1/log(n^3)

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I need to find the upper and lower bounds of this recursion: T(n)=2T(n/2)+1/log(n^3)

Any help? I just can't figure it out...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Master's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)):

```
a = 2
b = 2
```

therefore you have:

[image: fdgfdg]

which is larger than [image: dfgf]

So we have the first case of Master's theorem which implies:

[image: hgfh]

This is just the general complexity. For exact upper and lower bound you should use recursion or induction.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to solve it using "recursion tree" method and I got that T(n)=O(nlog(n)) and T(n)=Ω(n). Is this correct?